# Apache Spark with Apache Kafka integration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm new to Spark, and I am using Spark Structured Streaming (Spark 3.0.0, scala 2.12) to read data from kafka topic

I have 3 spark workers and the topic is divided into 3 partitions

correct me if I'm wrong but as I read from different answers and from Spark documentation , spark use consumer groups to read from kafka , and should map the executors as 1:1 with partitions if I have the same number of each

but when I check the consumer groups, I only find that one IP is consuming and it's the driver IP, so the data is not consumed directly from executors, and I found the tasks are only being divided for 2 executors and the third one is almost idle

So I have two questions:

- why only the driver node is consuming from kafka? and Can I get the executors in each worker to directly consume data from kafka?
- Can I divide the workload over all the executors?

```
object DataProcessing extends Serializable with Logging {

  val topics =  ""
  val brokers = ""

//window config => I'm using this during processing
  val windowDuration = s"2 hours"
  val slideDuration = s"15 minutes"
  
  @transient var streamingQuery: StreamingQuery = null

  val spark =
    SparkSession.builder
      .appName("app-name")
      .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
      .option("subscribe", topics)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "10000")
      .load()
    logDebug("Kafka Topic Data Schema => ")
    df.printSchema()

 
    val ds = df
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[(String, String)]

//extracting columns => transformations and groupings => windowedData

    val writer = new AuroraSink(url, username, password)
    streamingQuery = windowedData.writeStream
      .queryName("data-processor")
      .foreach(writer)
      .outputMode("update")
      .option("checkpointLocation", s"/data/$checkpoint")
      .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
      .start()
```

Comment: When you are using StructuredStreaming you should not rely on "Spark documentation of DirectStream" but rather refer to [Structured Streaming + Kafka integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). As Spark structured streaming is not committing any messages back to Kafka, checking the ConsumerGroups status in Kafka will not help. How are you running the application, in local or cluster mode? If in local, how many cores are available? Do you have data in all 3 partitions of the topic, or could one of them be empty?

Comment: You are reading the topic from "latest". How are you producing data into topic while the structured streaming job is running? Showing only the two variables `producer` and `streamingQuery` will not help without us knowing when and how they are being used in the code. Just defining them as `null` will not have any impact at all.

Comment: @mike I checked the link you sent as well, I got my understanding from this documentation , you can see in options `minPartitions` and `kafka.group.id` what I said

Comment: I modified the code and added my usage for `streamingQuery`, we can ignore the producer my fault that was from a different version you can ignore it,

Comment: I'm running on kubernetes, each worker node has 3 cores and 16GB of memory, the driver node has 2 cores and 10GB of memory , kafka topic is divided into 3 partitions , data is distributed in round robin , so they are balanced , spark is creating a consumer group , when I check the consumer group I find out that the driver is consuming all the partitions